# Decibel adjustment on Bode diagram

Tags: control-theory

Say we have the system $G(s) = 1/(s+1)^3$ with break frequency $\omega_b = 1$. Can someone explain to me why we should expect $|G(\omega_b)|$ to be $3$ dB below the low frequency asymptote, rather than 9 dB? I thought we were correcting once, with -3dB each, for every factor.

Comment: You are correct. If you do the calculation  $20\log_{10}(|G(j1)|)=-9.03$ i.e. -3dB for each pole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. If you do the calculation $20log_{10}(|G(j1)|)=−9.03$ i.e. -3dB for each pole. See the Bode below.
[image]